# How to loop play midi in MusicPlayer

Tags: ios5, audio, midi

I'm using below code to play a midi file in ios, but how can I loop the song?
is there sth like player.loop = true?

```
NewMusicSequence(&mySequence);
NSURL * midiFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:midPath];
MusicSequenceFileLoad(mySequence, (__bridge CFURLRef)midiFileURL, 0, kMusicSequenceLoadSMF_ChannelsToTracks);`

NewMusicPlayer(&player);
MusicPlayerSetSequence(player, mySequence);

MusicPlayerPreroll(player);
MusicPlayerStart(player);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it by setting loop info for each of the track.

```
 UInt32 tracks;


if (MusicSequenceGetTrackCount(sequence, &tracks) != noErr)


    for (UInt32 i = 0; i < tracks; i++) {
        MusicTrack track = NULL;
        MusicTimeStamp trackLen = 0;

        UInt32 trackLenLen = sizeof(trackLen);

        MusicSequenceGetIndTrack(sequence, i, &track);

        MusicTrackGetProperty(track, kSequenceTrackProperty_TrackLength, &trackLen, &trackLenLen);
        MusicTrackLoopInfo loopInfo = { trackLen, 0 };
        MusicTrackSetProperty(track, kSequenceTrackProperty_LoopInfo, &loopInfo, sizeof(loopInfo));
        NSLog(@"track length is %f", trackLen);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is having a problem looping a music sequence and following Rick Li's instructions, or the instructions here: https://gist.github.com/genedelisa/7b440f128db96c3ba66f , I found that MusicTrackLoopInfo code only worked when the duration of my track was *actually* short enough that I had the patience to sit and listen to it loop. For example, I tried to loop a track with a single click at the beginning so that it would repeat every second. But the **duration** of the single note was actually 100 seconds, so even if I set the looping as Rick Li explains above, I would have to wait nearly two minutes to hear it loop. I hope this helps someone who is confused or frustrated that they cannot get a music sequence / MIDI track to loop in iOS / AudioToolbox. Make sure to call GetProperty kSequenceTrackProperty_TrackLength and check that your trackLen is not some large value, even if you are convinced it is some small value!